# How can I resolve make error for Omnet++ for Windows 10?

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to install Omnet++ 5.4.1 on a 64-bit Windows 10 computer. When running make, I get an error:

> cd: animation: No such file or directory

There is such a directory under test/anim and it contains the files that make specifies:

```
for i in animation animation2 broadcast broadcast2 canvas changeparent [...] watch; do (cd $i && opp_makemake -f) || exit 1; done
```

What can I do to get on with the installation?

Comment: Welcome on SO! Have you done `./configure` before `make`? In which directory are you calling `make`? Moreover, could you call `make V=1` to extend verbose level and add a log into your question (using edit question option)? Usually the compilation of `OMNeT++` does not go into `test` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, the configure completes without problem. I run make in the main directory omnetpp-5.4.1

Comment: Running make V=1 gives:  

for i in animation animation2 broadcast broadcast2 canvas changeparent chartinspector disabledconn displaystring dynamic dynamic2 envirapi figureapi methodcall plugin refreshdisplay senddirect swarm texthalo usman watch; do (cd $i && opp_makemake -f) || exit 1; done
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: animation: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:9: makefiles] Error 1

Comment: Is it the **whole** log which gives `make V=1`?

Comment: Yup! I tried to move the listed folders (animation, animation2, ...) to the main directory and run make again, but it did not work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Take care that: 1) you have downloaded Windows version of `OMNeT++`, 2) the folder's path (where you have extracted `OMNeT++` archive) doesn't contain spaces, 3) real-time ant-virus scanning is disabled, 4) `./configure` and `make` are called from the main directory of `OMNeT++`.

Comment: Thanks Jerzy! The only thing I did not do was to turn off the antivirus (which needs administrative priviledge) - I will see if it helps.